# Ask matrix square and quadratic form

Tags: linear-algebra

In my applied multivariate statistical analysis textbook, it says  we are led naturally to consider a linear combination of the form

**c'X** = $c_1X_1+c_2X_2+ \cdot \cdot \cdot c_pX_p$ whose observed value on the *j*th trial is $\mathbf{c' x_j} = c_1 x_{j1} + c_2 x_{j2} +  \cdot \cdot \cdot c_p x_{jp}$, j=1,2,...,n.

Then to get sample variance, we need to verify this:

$$\mathbf{(c'x_j-c' \bar{x})^2 = (c'(x_j - \bar{x}))^2=c'(x_j-\bar{x})(x_j - \bar{x})'c}$$

I don't know how to understand this naturally. Because my first attempt is $\mathbf{(c'x_j-c' \bar{x})^2 =(c'(x_j-\bar{x}))^2}$. I don't see c here. I only see c'.